# Django：transaction.atomic によるトランザクション管理でBEGINコマンドが実行されず、select_for_update() でレコードのロックができない

Tags: python, mysql, django

Django でレコードの悲観ロックを実現しようと with transaction.atomic() 内で、select_for_update()を実行しましたが、レコードがロックされないです。
コードは以下です

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])
def Test(request):

  with transaction.atomic(using="test"):
    target_user = AdminUser.objects.select_for_update().get(id="test_user")
    target_user.name = "name"
    target_user.save()

  return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

これらが実行されるときは、以下のようなsqlコマンドが実行されると思っていました

```
BEGIN
SELECT ***** FOR UPDATE
COMMIT
```

しかし実際は、以下のような実行ログとなりました

```
SELECT ***** FOR UPDATE
COMMIT
```

バージョンに関して
Django 3.2.12
Python 3.6.15
Mysql 5.7.41

何かしらの設定が抜けているなどあればご指摘いただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

---

データベースエンジンにmysqlを利用しているのですが、django.db.backends.mysql には BEGINを実行するコマンドがなく、django.db.backends.sqlite3 にはありました

Answer (score 0):

以下のコードでトランザクションのカーソルにアクセスでき、sqlが実行できたのでBEGINしました。

```
from django.db import transaction, connections

with transaction.atomic(using="test"):
    connections["test"].cursor().execute("BEGIN")
```

transaction.atomic() がどのようにトランザクションを開始しているかライブラリを読むと django.db.transaction.get_connection で django.db.connectionsを呼び出しているのを確認。
connections[using]でデータベースエンジンごとのDatabaseWrapperオブジェクトからcursorを使っているようだったので、自前のViewでもconnections[using]を使うと同じトランザクション内でsqlが実行できた。